# How to change the ElevatedButton color or shadow Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I was using the `RaisedButton` untill the Flutter deprecated it and we couldn't use it anymore. There was a suggestion saying "Use `ElevatedButton` instead". So I tried using it but I couldn't see the properties like `color`, `elevation`, `focusColor` etc.

So how can I **personalize** an `ElevatedButton`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To change the properties of `ElevatedButton` you should be using the `style:` property like so:

```
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    primary: Colors.blue, //button's fill color
    onPrimary: Colors.red, //specify the color of the button's text and icons as well as the overlay colors used to indicate the hover, focus, and pressed states
    onSurface: Colors.orange, //specify the button's disabled text, icon, and fill color
    shadowColor: Colors.black, //specify the button's elevation color
    elevation: 4.0, //buttons Material shadow
    textStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'roboto'), //specify the button's text TextStyle
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0, bottom: 4.0, right: 8.0, left: 8.0), //specify the button's Padding
    minimumSize: Size(20, 40), //specify the button's first: width and second: height
    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.yellow, width: 2.0, style: BorderStyle.solid), //set border for the button
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0)), // set the buttons shape. Make its birders rounded etc
    enabledMouseCursor: MouseCursor.defer, //used to construct ButtonStyle.mouseCursor
    disabledMouseCursor: MouseCursor.uncontrolled, //used to construct ButtonStyle.mouseCursor
    visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0.0, vertical: 0.0), //set the button's visual density
    tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded, // set the MaterialTapTarget size. can set to: values, padded and shrinkWrap properties
    animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 100), //the buttons animations duration
    enableFeedback: true, //to set the feedback to true or false
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, //set the button's child Alignment
  ),
    onPressed: () => {} , //set both onPressed and onLongPressed to null to see the disabled properties
    onLongPress: () => {}, //set both onPressed and onLongPressed to null to see the disabled properties
    child: Text('ElevatedButton')
),
```

Answer (score 2):

- Change individual button color. Use **`style`** property.

  ```dart
  ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text('Button'),
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    ),
  )
  ```
- Change all buttons color down the widget tree. Use **`ElevatedButtonTheme`**:

  ```dart
  ElevatedButtonTheme(
    data: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red, // Sets color for all the descendant ElevatedButtons
      ),
    ),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('Button 1'),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 12),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('Button 2'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
  ```

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ElevatedButton.styleFrom** to change shadow and color.

```
 ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        primary: Colors.blue,
        shadowColor: Colors.black))
```